# angular select validation and selected attribute

Tags: angularjs

If I write this:

```
    <select name="udaljenosti_{$index}}" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="">Choose</option>
       <option ng-repeat="choice in attribute.Choices" value="{{choice.Id}}" ng-selected="choice.IsSelected==true">{{choice.Name}} </option>
     </select>
```

I don't get validation working.
But when I write this:

```
 <select name="udaljenosti_{{$index}}" ng-model="attribute.Choices.Name" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name  for item in attribute.Choices" class="form-control" required ng-required="true">
       <option value="">Choose</option>
 </select>
```

validation is working but I don't know how to prepopulate select with selected option (IsSeletected property from the first example)
This is JSON response:
[image]

Comment: Actually am confused.  What you want? do you want default selected option? or  what? And where you using validation code?

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran Read first example. Do you see something like this: ng-selected="choice.IsSelected==true". choice list has IsSelected attribute on it.

Comment: Yes  i saw that, ng-selected helps to set a default value. but you mean by it a validation purpose, That's a point for my confusion

Comment: Validation is not working in first example althought there is ng-required attribute. In second example validation is working but I don't know how to make third option selected(If we asume third option has IsSelected property we talked about)

Comment: If the question is not easy to understand I will clearfy. I don't see reason for downvoting.

Comment: can you tell what is the JSON for which you are making ng-options and value coming in ng-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't get any error

tried your code, with predefined value in ng-model.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select   ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-options="p.first as p.last for p in people" class="form-control" required ng-required="true">
       <option value="">Choose</option>
 </select>
     {{ selectedPerson }}
  </div>
</div>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble', actor: 'Arnold' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards', actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];
    $scope.selectedPerson = 'Ben'; 

}
```

here is the working jsfiddle [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14800/)

**you just need to make sure ,than value is ng-model is right**, in your case must match with what your **ID** AngularJS will automatically show you correct option selected in dropdown.

YOUR ERROR IS YOU ARE USING **ng-model="attribute.Choices.Name** , instead of **ng-model="attribute.Choices.Id**

Comment: I have more complicated situation. My select's are inside ng-repetar. I found solution. name="udaljenosti_{{$index}}" ng-model="udaljenosti_{{$index}}". ng-model and name must match to make validation working.

Comment: But there is another problem. i dont' know how to use {{}} interpolaction inside ng-model

Comment: wait. In ng-repeat , you don't need ng-model. ng-repat is independent of ng-model.

Comment: This helped: YOUR ERROR IS YOU ARE USING ng-model="attribute.Choices.Name , instead of ng-model="attribute.Choices.Id. Thanks

Comment: There is also one problem. When the selected is untouched and prepopulated from database I get error that is required when I submit the form.

Comment: you must be saving ID, not name?

Comment: Everything is fine,except one big problem. When option is prepopulated from database if I hit  submit i still get error that is required. Then I have to change select and select the some value again. After that if I click submit there is no errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75163/discussion-between-rishi-prakash-and-vlado).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code `ng-selected="attribute.choice[$index].IsSelected==true"`

try to use this instead of your code.

```
 <select name="udaljenosti_{{$index}}" ng-model="attribute.Choices.Name" 
 ng-options="item.Id as item.Name  for item in attribute.Choices"
 class="form-  control" required ng-required="true" 
 ng-selected=**"attribute.choice[$index].IsSelected==true"**>
                 <option value="">Choose</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: No, it is not working, I made edit on question to make it more understandable (I deleted "$index").(I have select elements inside ng-repeater, that's why I had $index in name attribute)