# Angular set error for required although option is selected

Tags: angularjs

I have this code (there is $index because select's are inside ng repeater, I have more than one dynimally generated)

```
<select name="udaljenosti_{{$index}}" ng-model="attribute.Choices.Id" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value=""  >--Choose--</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="choice in attribute.Choices" value="{{choice.Id}}" ng-selected="choice.IsSelected==true">
                        {{choice.Name}} </option>
                </select>
```

There is IsSelected property on choice as you can see. If all choices have IsSelected==false, on submit I get error that some option is required because of required property on select, and when I choose some option on select and hit submit there is no error. Very good, so far. But, when some option is prepopulated from the database there is some strange behaviour. Everything seems good but when I click submit angular says there is error on select field. It says select is required but some option is already selected!! 
EDIT: it seems name ang ng-model should much. How to accomplish this because I get error if I put uudaljenosti_{{$index}} inside ng-model?

Comment: use `ng-options` instead of an `ng-repeat`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#!/

Comment: In that case required is not working. See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604123/angular-select-validation-and-selected-attribute

Comment: That's not what I see. In both your examples you are using ng-repeat, in all the answers thy are using ng-options.

Comment: Read again. If I use ng options prepulating is not working.

Comment: what does the answer you accepted, which says "YOUR ERROR IS YOU ARE USING ng-model="attribute.Choices.Name , instead of ng-model="attribute.Choices.Id"" have to do with ng-options vs ng-repeat?

Comment: "ng-repeat solution" is OK excepted the problem if some option is already prepoluated and user has not touched the select I get error that is required.How  is  it required when the option is already selected :(